# display issue in qgis 2.14 : features appear and disappear

Tags: qgis, display, spatial-index

I have several virtual layers in my project. One of them contains 6 lines. Depending of the scale, at least one line disappears from the canvas for an unknown reason.
I heard that sometimes, creating spatial index solve the problem.
I tried to create an index for this virtual layer according to spatialite sql (select CreateSpatialIndex('table', 'geometry')) but it fails (returns 0), i don't know the reason why.
Question : why does the index fail and/but is the display problem really linked to the spatial index ?
Here are two pictures with two differents scales.[image: scale 1:47]

[image: scale 1:80]

edit : added shared data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1yuAbW2T79iU0hDUFpFanZWLTg/view?usp=sharing

SQL :

```
select t1.* from "Tours_cupidon_unobs_ordre_rendu" 
as t0,"Tours_cupidon_unobs_ordre_rendu" as t1 
where st_distance(st_centroid(t0.geometry), st_centroid(t1.geometry)) 
<4 and t0.num = 314 AND t1.typFait = 'sep'

select t1.num, make_line(centroid( t0.geometry), centroid(t1.geometry)) 
as geometry from "Tours_cupidon_unobs_ordre_rendu" as t0
, "Tours_cupidon_unobs_ordre_rendu" as t1
where t0.num = 314 and t1.num in (324,325,334,347,348,349,3142,3153,3162)AND t1.typFait = 'sep' and t1.typunobs = 'fait'
```

Comment: Have you checked Geometry Validity?

Comment: yes i did : no problem.

Comment: Can you share (part of) the data?

Comment: sure, done in first post

Comment: @Leehan - Perhaps it's just me but I cannot load your virtual layers. Haven't used these types of layers before but I assumed they were saved in the .qgs project file?

Comment: yes they are saved in the project. I used the link I gave to test and it works fine here, You opened with QGis 2.14 ?

Comment: Those virtual layers are stored in the project file with absolute paths to your hard disk (so no problem starting on your PC, but noone else can load them). Only one shapefile is included, and that performs normal. Can you save the other (virtual) layers as shapefiles into the same folder, and include them into your zip file?

Comment: saving virtual layers resolve my problem : all entities appear. I want to keep virtual layers, I think you guess why (lighter, less clics,...). But from the layer in the project, you can create 2 virtual layers with the display bug. I just added the sql in first post to create the virtual layers.